# Why are SMS messages sent on my Samsung Galaxy S III running AOKP appear as unable to be sent?

Tags: sms, samsung-galaxy-s-3, aokp

Why are SMS messages sent on my Samsung Galaxy S III running AOKP appear as unable to be sent? The SMS is actually sent.

I tested with a message to myself:

[image]

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Edit: I forgot to add that I have done this very recently. So there has not been a period where it worked normally. This occurred as soon as I flashed the ROM.